# Approximating Delta distribution with an Exponential

Tags: dirac-delta

Is it alright to approximate a Delta distribution with an exponential like this:

$$\delta(x-1) = \omega\,e^{-\omega (x-1)}, \hspace{1cm} x \geq 1,$$

where, $\omega \gg 1 $, and,
$$\int_1^{\infty} f(x)\,\delta(x-1) = f(1).$$ Also, what are the caveats of differentiating  this distribution, e.g., can I write,
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\delta(x-1) = -\omega\,\delta(x-1).$$

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The approximation you use for $\delta(x)$ is
$D_\omega(x) = \omega e^{-\omega x} H(x),$
where $H$ is the Heaviside step function.
The derivative of this is
$$
D_\omega'(x) 
= -\omega^2 e^{-\omega x} H(x) + \omega e^{-\omega x} \delta(x)
= -\omega D_\omega(x) + \omega \delta(x)
.
$$

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. However, can we say that $D'_{\omega}(x)$ is approximately zero, since $D_{\omega}(x) \approx \delta (x)$?

Comment: @devanshushekhar. No, the difference $D_\omega - \delta$ is small when $\omega$ is large, but then you multiply this with the large value $\omega$ and get a not so small distribution. Actually, $\delta - D_\omega \approx \frac{1}{\omega} \delta'.$

Answer (score 0):

The Dirac Delta has a standard regularization by the family of normed Gaussians
$$\delta_\varepsilon (x) = \frac{1} {\sqrt{2\pi \varepsilon^2}} \  e^{- \frac{x^2}{2 \varepsilon^2}}$$
that has unit 1-norm and falls off to zero sudenly for $|x| > 3 \varepsilon$.
The central points of a regularization of the $\delta$-distribution:

1. Approximate point support at $x=0$,
2. approximate unit step function of its indefinite integral,
3. indefinite differentiability (smoothness) to implement the unlimited algebra of partial differentiation of products with smooth functions of compact support.

Check your approach against the thre points.

Comment: Hi, I have considered Gaussian distribution earlier, bu the problem is its first derivative would yield an extra x, which when evaluated at 0 makes everything 0. How do I deal with this issue?

Comment: Thats correct, it reprents $\delta'$ as a dipole distribution  of two opposite charges going to infinitiy with distance. 0.  Any derivative  $\delta^{(n)}$ maps to the derivative of the smooth factor  of compact support under the integral, yielding $f^{(n)}(0)$.

Comment: What I mean is, let $f^{(1)}(x)$ at $x=0$ is not zero, but since $\delta^{(1)}(x) = x \delta{(x)}$, $f(x) x $ at $x = 0$ becomes 0. So is it correct to approximate $\delta(x)$ with a Gaussian?

Comment: $ f  \delta'   != x f \delta$. Try $f=(x-1)^2\delta' (x)  \to - 2(x-1) \delta(x)$

Comment: Yes, but what if I want to differentiate the $\delta(x)$ itself, rather than using integrating by parts and differentiating $f(x)$, since I know the functional form of $\delta(x)$, which is a Gaussian. In that case, we'll get $-x(x-1)^2 \delta(x)$, which is quite different than what we get the other way. Am I missing something?

Comment: @devanshushekhar. Why do you think that $\delta'(x) = x\delta(x)$? That's not true.

Comment: Well, actually, I meant $\delta'(x)=\frac{x}{\epsilon^2} \delta(x).$ Because, when you differentiate the Gaussian function, we get the extra factor of $\frac{x}{\epsilon^2}$, and the remaining is the delta according to the definition. Does this make sense?